# Run function until user clicks a button

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to develop an app that includes a metronome, repeating a tone at an interval specified by the user. I'm able to get the metronome to play - this is triggered by an onClick event, but the app becomes locked in the `startMetronome()` function I created. I know why this is, I was just mostly trying to ensure that I was able to get the tone to play and have it repeat at the user defined intervals:

```
private fun startMetronome(interval: Long) {
        while (true) {
            soundPool?.play(soundId, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
            Thread.sleep(interval)
        }
    }
```

Obviously this never leaves the `startMetronome()` function and locks the app (again, I expect this). I'm just not sure how to trigger this function and then allow the app buttons to still be active, allowing for an "interrupt" to be triggered and this function to be then started with an adjusted interval.

Comment: Why are you using the `Thread.sleep()` in the first place? That just wastes resources by blocking the thread, Use coroutines functions like `delay()` or any other asynchronous method that does not block threads.

Comment: I just used the first thing I thought of to test the "delay" to confirm that the actual sounds were playing at the correct interval. But thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a coroutine like this. Not sure how accurate the timing would be.

```
private var metronomeJob: Job? = null

private fun startMetronome(interval: Long) {
    metronomeJob?.cancel()
    metronomeJob = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (isActive) {
            soundPool?.play(soundId, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
            delay(interval)
        }
    }
}

private fun stopMetronome() {
    metronomeJob?.cancel()
    metronomeJob = null
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This mostly works, but when the interval is shorter than 1 second (interval = 1000) there becomes a lot of distortion and clipping. Hard to tell if it's the audio file itself, or what because the audio becomes so chaotic. Essentially, my test has been 30bpm (fine), 60bpm (fine), 61bpm (issues arise). Any guess at what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Sorry, no. I haven't worked with audio playback much.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start the sound on another thread so it doesn't block the UI Thread, the most basic way to do this would be via a Async Task

Pseudo code:

```
private class playSoundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     protected Void doInBackground(Integer... interval) {
           if (!isCancelled()){
             //start playing the sound
           } else{
            //stop playing the sound
           } 
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
        
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      
     }
 }
```

To start the task call `playSoundTask().execute();`
To stop the task call `playSoundTask().cancel();`